# Operation between pandas datetime-indexed DataFrames with non-equal elements

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, operation

I have two pandas Dataframes with non-equal elements, but they are indexed. I'd like to divide them, index by index, without have to interpolate.

DataFrame1 =

```
                                tbr45       tbl45       tbr90       tbl90  \
2013-09-09 11:35:00+00:00  481.205292  458.953156  572.320435  559.995605   
2013-09-09 11:36:00+00:00  484.707611  462.304871  573.970215  561.364807   
2013-09-09 11:37:00+00:00  488.629181  466.664246  578.624695  564.752808   
2013-09-09 11:38:00+00:00  490.437164  468.294403  580.286316  565.774475   
2013-09-09 11:39:00+00:00  492.522095  471.054016  582.710510  568.416321   
2013-09-09 11:40:00+00:00  494.583923  473.001190  584.202637  571.518433   
2013-09-09 11:41:00+00:00  498.174072  477.333557  586.001465  574.513794
```

DataFrame2 =

```
                                tbr45       tbl45       tbr90       tbl90    
2013-09-09 11:41:00+00:00  498.174072  477.333557  586.001465  574.513794   
2013-09-09 11:42:00+00:00  499.323181  478.827942  587.080750  576.497192   
2013-09-09 11:43:00+00:00  502.315674  483.138062  589.863647  579.052368   
2013-09-09 11:44:00+00:00  503.036499  484.466675  592.452515  580.705750   
2013-09-09 11:45:00+00:00  505.769226  486.743713  595.071167  582.199707   
2013-09-09 11:46:00+00:00  507.393738  488.528107  597.469421  583.763977   
2013-09-09 11:47:00+00:00  509.901398  491.445221  598.312622  584.742004   
2013-09-09 11:48:00+00:00  511.310791  493.962524  600.510742  587.291992
```

For this case, the operation DataFrame2/DataFrame1, obviously, have only one element at 11:41:00, with the result 1, 1, 1, 1. The another results could be NaN

Actually, I have data for several days, and interpolate one by one is a dificult option. Maybe using `apply` but I dont know how.

Comment: Sorry are you asking to divide your df and ignore the index? if so then `DataFrame2/DataFrame1.values` should work

Comment: I just want to operate between the dataframes (divide, multiply, sum, etc), but the operation must be index by index, for this case the only one index between them is at 11:41:00, so could be the operation done only for this index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide dataframes this way: `result = df2.divide(df1, axis='index')`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u""";tbr45;tbl45;tbr90;tbl90
2013-09-09 11:35:00+00:00;481.205292;458.953156;572.320435;559.995605
2013-09-09 11:36:00+00:00;484.707611;462.304871;573.970215;561.364807
2013-09-09 11:37:00+00:00;488.629181;466.664246;578.624695;564.752808
2013-09-09 11:38:00+00:00;490.437164;468.294403;580.286316;565.774475
2013-09-09 11:39:00+00:00;492.522095;471.054016;582.710510;568.416321
2013-09-09 11:40:00+00:00;494.583923;473.001190;584.202637;571.518433
2013-09-09 11:41:00+00:00;498.174072;477.333557;586.001465;574.513794"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=[0])
print df1

temp1=u""";tbr45;tbl45;tbr90;tbl90
2013-09-09 11:41:00+00:00;498.174072;477.333557;586.001465;574.513794
2013-09-09 11:42:00+00:00;499.323181;478.827942;587.080750;576.497192
2013-09-09 11:43:00+00:00;502.315674;483.138062;589.863647;579.052368
2013-09-09 11:44:00+00:00;503.036499;484.466675;592.452515;580.705750
2013-09-09 11:45:00+00:00;505.769226;486.743713;595.071167;582.199707
2013-09-09 11:46:00+00:00;507.393738;488.528107;597.469421;583.763977
2013-09-09 11:47:00+00:00;509.901398;491.445221;598.312622;584.742004
2013-09-09 11:48:00+00:00;511.310791;493.962524;600.510742;587.291992"""

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), sep=";", index_col=[0])
print df2

result = df2.divide(df1, axis='index')
print result
#                           tbr45  tbl45  tbr90  tbl90
#2013-09-09 11:35:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:36:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:37:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:38:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:39:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:40:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:41:00+00:00      1      1      1      1
#2013-09-09 11:42:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:43:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:44:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:45:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:46:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:47:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
#2013-09-09 11:48:00+00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: What operation support this way? I try 'df2.multiply' it's work, but what else can be carry out?